# Mock is not returning setup value

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, xunit.net

I've below method which I'm unit testing using Xunit and Moq.

```
public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public PersonService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork));
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<int> PostPersonAsync(PersonModel person)
    {
        int result = 0;

        using (_unitOfWork.Connection)
        {
            try
            {
                _unitOfWork.OpenConnection();

                _unitOfWork.Begin();

                var PersonDto = _mapper.Map<PersonDto>(person);

                result = await _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.PostPersonAsync(PersonDto, _unitOfWork.Transaction);

                _unitOfWork.Commit();

                _unitOfWork.CloseConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Below is my Xunit method:

```
[Fact]
public void PostPersonAsync_Should_SavePerson()
{
    //Arrange
    var _IDbTransaction = new Mock<IDbTransaction>();
    var _unitOfWorkMock1 = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
  
    
    var PersonDto = _mapper.Map<PersonDto>(PersonServiceData.PersonModel);
    int numberofAffectedRows = 5;
    _unitOfWorkMock1.Setup(s => s.OpenConnection());
    _unitOfWorkMock1.Setup(s => s.PersonRepository.PostPersonAsync(PersonDto, _IDbTransaction.Object)).ReturnsAsync(()=>numberofAffectedRows);
    _unitOfWorkMock1.Setup(s => s.CloseConnection());
    
    _target = new PersonService(_unitOfWorkMock1.Object, _mapper);

    //Act
    var result = _target.PostPersonAsync(PersonServiceData.PersonModel).Result;

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(5, result);
}
```

I'm not sure why it still returns zero, and my test case fails.

I've also tried with the below, but still, my test case fails.

```
_unitOfWorkMock1.Setup(s => s.PersonRepository.PostPersonAsync(PersonDto, _IDbTransaction.Object)).ReturnsAsync(()=>numberofAffectedRows);
```

Even after setting up the return value for the repository method call, it is returning zero.

Comment: Any time that happens it is usually because the setup does not match what was actually passed in. loosen up the argument match using `It.IsAny<>()`.  Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use MOQ

Comment: I've tried that and it is not working. It still returns zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
_unitOfWorkMock1
    .Setup(s => s.PersonRepository.PostPersonAsync(It.IsAny<PersonDto>(), It.IsAny<IDbTransaction>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(numberofAffectedRows);
```

Comment: It was the transaction that has to be used with It.IsAny and causing the issue. Thanks.